# Amazon S3 上の画像を独自ドメインの URL で参照することは可能か

Tags: amazon-s3

Rails 6で作成したブログサイトにて、Amazon S3に保存している投稿画像をHerokuを使って取得してます。

以下のようなurlになります。

`https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/article/picture1/78/window.png`

ブログのURLのドメインと画像URLのドメインが一致させたいのですが、方法はありますでしょうか？

`https://example.com/uploads/article/picture1/78/window.png`

のように `https://example.com` から始めたいです。

そうすることで、他の共用ブログサービスサイトでも、投稿画像の取得が可能になります。

Amazon S3の設定変更でできるのか、自分の開発環境の変更でできるのか、もしくはAmazon S3ではなく他のストレージサービスを使えばできるのか、やり方がわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

なんか出来そうですね

【AWS】S3画像のURLを独自ドメイン（サブドメイン）にする
https://brainlog.jp/server/aws/post-3180/